# Magento 2: How to get the product price with currency symbol in PHTML file with help of block

Tags: magento2, product-prices

From the `$product` object I am getting the collection of product from block and to render the fields. I want to get the price with it's currency code like 
`$99.00` in product listing.

Right now, I am using the below code to get the price of the product but i need to display the price with currency symbol.

```
$product->getFinalPrice();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

create a object of `abstractProduct` Block then call the `getProductPrice` method and pass **product object** as parameter. see below.

```
$abstractProductBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct');
echo $abstractProductBlock->getProductPrice($product);
```

Complete implementation  example:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$abstractProductBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct');

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->setPageSize(8)
            ->load();
?>
<div>
    <?php foreach ($collection as $product) :?>
        <div class="item-box">
            <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>" >
                <span class="imgbx">
                    <img src="<?php echo $abstractProductBlock->getImage($product, 'latest_collection_list')->getImageUrl(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>" />
                </span>
                <h3><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></h3>
                <span class="hm-price"><?php echo $abstractProductBlock->getProductPrice($product) ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;  ?>
</div>
?>
```

Comment: Using object manager in Magento 2 is a bad practice. This answer should not be followed.

Comment: The above getProductprice() can get the configurable product price???

Comment: I got the product collection which consists both simple and configurable products. I need to get price for each products. If simple comes means it easily get the price. But in the case of configure product, how it will get the price

Comment: @Arun Karnawat, I got the price of the simple product by referring​ Ur code

Comment: Struggling to get configurable product price

Answer (score 10):

```
// Instance of Object Manager

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

// Instance of Pricing Helper

$priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data'); 

echo $priceHelper->currency($product->getFinalPrice(), true, false);
```

Comment: You should never use ObjectManager directly in Magento. If you really need Pricing Helper, you can inject it to the block or use `->getHelper()`

Comment: @Łukasz thanks for the answer, anyway this was old thing, in 2017 hard to find help for magento 2, actually now I'm not doing magento

Answer (score 6):

On Magento 2 in my custom Theme, I'm simply using this on the **product page in the phtml** file.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');    

$price = $product->getPrice();
```

Or this in any **other phtml file**.

The difference is because on this example I'm getting by product ID instead of the current product.

*In this case, you can set the ID to bring the desired product price. On the example, I get the ID of the current product.*

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');                                       
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productid);

$price = $product->getPrice();
```

And I'm using this code line to **format price**.

Before: `7.000` >>>> After: `£7.00`

```
$priceFormatted = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($product->getPrice(), 2), true, false);
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael, your answer saved my time.

Comment: @Rafael I tried both the option but it did not work for me. I want to get product details in amount/default.phtml file.

Comment: @Nafisa Could you please post the full relative path and te error your are seeing?

Comment: currency symbol is showing after the product price

Answer (score 1):

You can get your current currency symbol from `Magento\Directory\Model\Currency`
so just intitialize it in your construct function and call method `getCurrencySymbol()` for get current currecy symbol:

```
$currencyCode = $this->_currency->getCurrencySymbol();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml
```

You could just use this in order to get the price with the currency.

```
<?php echo $block->getProductPrice($product); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the price for multiple products, without the usual HTML wrapping.

```php
/** @var $priceHelper \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data */
$priceHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');
/** @var $_item \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product **/
foreach($_items as $_item){
    $finalPrice = $_item->getPriceInfo()
        ->getPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE)
        ->getMinimalPrice()
        ->getValue();
    echo '<strong>Price: '.$priceHelper->currency($finalPrice, false, false).'</strong>';
}
```

This will print the price of all products, with the currency symbol for the current store as well as round to correct decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

**Block File**

```
protected $resultLayout;
protected $_productloader;

public function __construct(
    ..............................
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $resultLayout,
    ..............................
) {
    ..............................
    $this->resultLayout = $resultLayout;
    $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
    ..............................
}

..............................

public function getProductPriceHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render $priceRender */
    $priceRender = $this->resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class);
    if (!$priceRender) {
        $priceRender = $this->resultLayout->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class,
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class,
            ['data' => ['price_render_handle' => 'catalog_product_prices']]
        );
    }
    $price = '';
    if ($priceRender) {
        $price = $priceRender->render(
            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
            $product,
            [
                'display_minimal_price' => true,
                'use_link_for_as_low_as' => true,
                'zone' => \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
            ]
        );
    }

    return $price;
}

public function getProductData($id)
{
    return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
}
```

**phtml File**

```
$productid = 1088;

$product = $block->getProductData($productid);

echo $block->getProductPriceHtml($product);
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***